# Is there a better way to delete Associations?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have Friends and Categories - each Friend belongs to a category. Here is how they are related:

in the **Category Class**:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friend", mappedBy="category", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $friends;
```

and in **Friend Class**:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="friends")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;
```

What I want is to delete a category and when this happens, the friends which belonged to this category to have a category = null. Is there a way to make this more elegant?

As you see, I tried with `cascade={"remove"}` and it's perfect, but it deletes the friends, too. Is there a better solution then selecting all friends from the current category, setting their category field to null and then deleting the category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `onDelete` in `@JoinColumn` and set it to `set null`. [Here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) are docs for this.

Comment: I tried this `/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="friends")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="SET NULL")
     */` over the property `$category` in **Friend** class and left the annotations as in the question for the property `$friends` in the **Category** class, and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Use `onDelete="SET NULL"` and remove the `cascade={"remove"}` annotation. It will work.

Comment: Thanks! I forgeted to update database schema, too, but after doing it and what you said it works.